# about layouts in ruby on rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm studying Ruby on Rails by Ruby on Rails Tutorial.
I did test but, I found error.
Where is wrong?

```
test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1451158535.88s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `full_title' for #<#<Class:0x007ff2da1e0bc0>:0x007ff2da1dbeb8>
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2067729572228884173_70340508945500'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2067729572228884173_70340508945500'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not damn sure but Its my assumption that you would be following [Ch 3- Testing Titles](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-testing_titles)

It seems there `full_title` has not been defined.

Just write

```
@full_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
```

Hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the method `full_title` is not defined.

Make sure that it's properly defined in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`.

Here is my `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(title="")
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if title.blank?
      base_title
    else
      "#{title} | #{base_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

And don't forget to edit `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file as well:

```
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                       'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track'     => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render "layouts/shim" %>
</head>
```

Per the implementaion of `full_title` method, it returns either `base_title` (i.e the string `Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App`), or `"The title of your choice" | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App` if you pass in the title as an argument to the method, which you can do by putting `<% provide :title, "your title here" %>` on each page.)

Hope it helps!